# How to use php to replace periods with bullets (li)?

Tags: php

I have a string in php with multiple periods.  I am trying to figure out to replace each of the periods in the string into a bullet (`<li>`) on a new line.  Does anyone have advice on how to do this?

```
$desc= "Petite Jeans. Petite Fit Guide,Tall Fit Guide Explore our 1969 denim boutique for fit facts, fabric notes, style tips, and more. Fabrication: Premium stretch denim. Wash: Faded dark blue. Hardware: Double button closure, zip fly. Features: Five pocket styling. Cut: Mid rise. Fit: Slim through the hip and thigh. Leg opening: Boot cut. Inseams: regular: 33\', tall: 37\', petite: 30\'";

echo $desc;
```

The above string should look like:

```
<li>Petite Jeans. 
<li>Petite Fit Guide,Tall Fit Guide Explore our 1969 denim boutique for fit facts, fabric notes, style tips, and more. 
<li>Fabrication: Premium stretch denim. 
<li>Wash: Faded dark blue. 
<li>Hardware: Double button closure, zip fly. 
<li>Features: Five pocket styling. 
<li>Cut: Mid rise. 
<li>Fit: Slim through the hip and thigh. 
<li>Leg opening: Boot cut. 
<li>Inseams: regular: 33\', tall: 37\', petite: 30\'
```

Comment: i could provide a solution easy enough so long as there was only ever a period at the end of each line and not more than one on a line. is this the case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're sure that every period can be replaced, what you want is `implode()` and `explode()`:

```
$desc = '<li>' . implode('</li><li>', explode('.', $desc)) . '</li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$desc = '<li>' . str_replace('.','</li><li>', $desc) . '</li>';
```

http://ideone.com/Z62S5

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$bulletted = str_replace(".", "<br />&bull;", $desc);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php